# Assigning Axios fetched data to Vuex State from Vuex Action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuex

As per the Axios [documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#example), I concurrently fetch two data sources from my backed (`block.json` and `type.json`) within `actions` of my Vuex store. In my Vuex State, I declare `myBlocks` and `myTypes` as data. The data is fetched fine, but I cannot seem to assign the fetched data to the variables in the Vuex state. I seem to have troubles referencing the state, because `console.log(state.sample)` yields `undefined` rather than `foo`. However, `console.log(state)` yields the following as in the photograph below. Any leads would be great.
[image]

```
state: {
  sample: 'foo',
  myBlocks: [],
  myTypes: []

},


actions: {
  fetchElementColors: function(state) {
      function getElementBlockColors() { return axios.get('/element-data/block.json'); }
      function getCategoryDataColors() { return axios.get('/element-data/type.json'); }

      axios.all([getElementBlockColors(), getCategoryDataColors()])
        .then(axios.spread(function(blockData, categoryData) {
          console.log(state);
          console.log(state.sample);
          state.myBlocks= blockData.data;
          state.myTypes= categoryData.data;
        }));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `actions`, you are not provided with `state` but `context`.

So you need to do as follows:

```
actions: {
  fetchElementColors: function(context) {
      function getElementBlockColors() { return axios.get('/element-data/block.json'); }
      function getCategoryDataColors() { return axios.get('/element-data/type.json'); }

      axios.all([getElementBlockColors(), getCategoryDataColors()])
        .then(axios.spread(function(blockData, categoryData) {
          console.log(context.state);
          console.log(context.state.sample);
          context.state.myBlocks= blockData.data;
          context.state.myTypes= categoryData.data;
        }));
    }

}
```

Reference: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html